# Makefile with PATH environment variable on Mac

Tags: macos, makefile, environment-variables, qemu

I am trying to execute qemu-system-arm within Makefile compilation. I have already edited:

- .bash_profile
- .profile
- /etc/paths

And it works fine in shell command which `$qemu-system-arm`, but my Makefile does not works.
Here is my sample Makefile:

```
qemu:
     qemu-system-arm -machine help
```

I get this errors with command `$make qemu` :

```
qemu-system-arm -machine help
make: qemu-system-arm: No such file or directory
make: *** [qemu] Error 1
```

By the way, my qemu wasn't installed by brew, because I need another platform such like stm32-p103. So after building my own qemu, I have to set $PATH accordingly.

Here is my os version:

```
macOS Mojave v10.14.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When make executes the recipes of a rule it passes it to the shell. So, in order to use `qemu-system-arm` the shell must know where to find it. This depends on which shell make uses (`sh`, `bash`, other?) and which configuration file this shell reads at start-up (`~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, other?).

You can investigate with a simple test rule in your makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
...
.PHONY: test
test:
    echo 'SHELL=$(SHELL)'
...
$ make test
SHELL=...
```

In your case the shell is probably not the bourne shell (`sh`) because `~/.profile` is read by `sh`, so it would probably work. So, it could be that the shell used by make is `bash`: as the shell spawned by make is not a login shell it does not read `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`. You must add the `PATH` definition to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
 echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/qemu-system-arm' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Or, if you do not want to alter all you bash processes, you can add this definition to your Makefile (environment variables become make variables in the make context):

```
$ cat Makefile
PATH := $(PATH):/path/to/qemu-system-arm
...
```

Note that you can also force make to use the shell you want (but consider that it negatively impacts the portability of your makefile):

```
 SHELL := /usr/local/bin/my-preferred-shell
```